# Where is my pom.xml file in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

Right now I added the MongoDB driver, a jar file, to my project library so I can use the driver. But I want to use Maven. I have the dependency:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and I know I am supposed to add it to a pom.xml file. However even with internet searches I can't find out where the pom.xml file is.

Comment: your `pom.xml` should be in the project's root directory

Comment: Do you have maven project ? if not first convert it into maven

Answer (score 1):

It must be in your root directory. Go to your project location in the file system. If you project is of maven nature, there must be a `pom.xml`.

If not, no worries.

If you are using Eclipse IDE, you can convert your project into maven project by *right-click on the project and click configure and then convert to maven project*.

If you installed maven explicitly (I mean not plugin only), You can create a new maven project and add your mongo dependency there.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} 
-DartifactId={project-name} 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/).